# Minimizing the sum of the tangents of the half-angles of a triangle

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

In a given $\triangle ABC$ what can be the minimum value of

$$\tan(\angle A/2) + \tan(\angle B/2) + \tan(\angle C/2)$$

I think it will be minimal in case of an equilateral triangle but I can't prove it

Context:
I had the problem of minimising the sum
$$\tan^2(\angle A/2) + \tan^2(\angle B/2) + \tan^2(\angle C/2)$$ which I wrote as

$$(\tan(\angle A/2) + \tan(\angle B/2) + \tan(\angle C/2))^2-2(\tan(\angle A/2)\tan(\angle B/2)+\tan(\angle C/2)\tan(\angle B/2)+\tan(\angle C/2)\tan(\angle A/2))$$

And the second term here is a constant which is one.

Comment: See [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality)

Comment: Could you provide a more elementary approach that does not involve calculus?

Comment: Yes I can work with cauchy Schwarz but please provide more details

Comment: You've posed a problem that can be resolved by reasoned mathematical argument, but omitted important context such as the source of the problem or its motivation/importance/difficulty.  As your Comments reveal, you have definite wishes regarding what techniques can be used in the solution, so clarification of context is called for.  Voting to close.

Comment: @hardmath It was all fine until now and I had also recieved some solutions. I don't know what is your problem.

Comment: I'm glad you received help, but consider the benefit to future Readers if you supplied the missing context.  The [Quick Tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and other Help Center articles may explain the importance of supplying context better.

Comment: Ok now I have provided the relevant context. How do I reopen it?

Comment: Okay, it's a little cryptic but I'm able to follow your thinking.  Voting to reopen.  Your edit will already have put this Question into the review queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of $\frac12\angle A,\frac12\angle B,\frac13\angle C$, let's call the three half angles as $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$.

Let $t_i = \tan\theta_i$ for $i = 1,2,3$.

Notice $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 = \frac{\pi}{2}$.
By [tangent addition formula for 3 angles](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tangent_of_Sum_of_Three_Angles)
${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$, we have
$$\infty = \tan(\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3) = \frac{t_1 + t_2 + t_3 - t_1 t_2 t_3}{1 - (t_1 t_2 + t_2 t_3 + t_3 t_1)}$$
Notice $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3 \in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, $t_1,t_2,t_3$ are finite numbers. In order to get $\infty$, the denominator at RHS needs to vanish. This leads to the equality
$$t_1 t_2 + t_2 t_3 + t_3 t_1 = 1$$
Apply Cauchy Schwarz to the 3 tuples $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ and $(t_2,t_3,t_1)$, we obtain

$$t_1^2 + t_2^2 + t_3^2 \ge t_1 t_2 + t_2 t_3 + t_3 t_1 = 1$$
As a result,

$$(t_1 + t_2 + t_3)^2 
= t_1^2 + t_2^2 + t_3^2 + 2(t_1t_2 + t_2t_3 + t_3t_1)
\ge 3$$
and hence
$$
\tan \theta_1 + \tan \theta_2  + \tan \theta_3 = t_1 + t_2 + t_3 \ge \sqrt{3}$$

This lower bound $\sqrt{3}$ is achieved at $\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \theta_3 = \frac{\pi}{6}$, ie. when $\triangle ABC$ is an equilateral triangle.

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - This a special case of a [more general formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tangent_of_Sum_of_Series_of_Angles).

> Given $n$ angles $\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n$,
> $$\tan\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\theta_k\right) =
> \frac{ s_1 - s_3 + s_5 - \cdots }{1 - s_2 + s_4 - \cdots}$$
> where $\displaystyle\;
> s_k = \sum_{\stackrel{S \subset \{1,\ldots,n\}}{ |S| = k}} \prod_{j \in S}\tan\theta_j\;$

Comment: Although I agree with the solution, and it had occurred to me before, I am not sure whether concluding $1 - (t_1 t_2 + t_2 t_3 + t_3 t_1) = 0$ from $\infty = \frac{t_1 + t_2 + t_3 - t_1 t_2 t_3}{1 - (t_1 t_2 + t_2 t_3 + t_3 t_1)}$ is valid....

Comment: @DS Since all $\theta_i \in (0,\pi/2)$, all $t_i$ are finite numbers. In order for $\tan(\sum\theta_i) = \infty$, the denominator need to vanish.

Comment: @DS   $\theta_1+\theta_2 = 90-\theta_3$ applying tan on both sides and simplifying also gives the same result

Answer (score 4):

We will show that

> Given $x,y,z>0$ s.t. $x+y+z = \pi/2$, $$\tan(x)+\tan(y)+\tan(z) \ge \sqrt 3$$

---

I still believe [Jensen](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1774585p11660798) is the best way. Since the OP asks for a non-calculus approach, here are a few hints:

1. First, show that for $x,y \in (0,\pi/2)$
   $$\boxed{\tan(x)+\tan(y) \ge 2\tan((x+y)/2)}$$
   with equality iff $\boxed{x=y}$.
   This is equivalent to showing$$\cos^2((x+y)/2) \ge \cos(x)\cos(y)$$which is true since $\cos^2((x+y)/2) = (\cos(x+y)+1)/2$ and $\cos(x)\cos(y) = (\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y))/2$. This reduces the problem to$$1\ge\cos(x-y)$$and the equality case is also clear.
2. Then, note that for $x>0$,
   $$\boxed{2x+\frac{1-x^2}{2x} \ge \sqrt 3}$$
   with equality iff $\boxed{x = 1/\sqrt 3}$.
   This should be easy as simplification leads to
   $$(\sqrt 3x - 1)^2 = 3x^2-2\sqrt3x + 1 \ge 0$$
   This can also be done by using AM-GM
   $$\frac{1+3x^2}{2x} \ge \frac{\sqrt3x}{x} = \sqrt3$$
3. Observe that $$\boxed{\tan(z)} = \tan(\pi/2 - (x+y)) = \cot(x+y) = 1/\tan(x+y) = \boxed{\frac{1-\tan^2((x+y)/2)}{2\tan((x+y)/2)}}$$
4. Now, use the above three steps to prove the inequality. Also verify that the equality cases do not contradict each other and that equality is possible.